# Dell iDrac with SSH Tunneling : administratively prohibited open failed

Tags: ssh, dell, tunneling, drac, failed

I've a problem to access to my iDrac interface over SSH.

I want access to my iDrac WebUI by SSH Tunneling but I've this error :

> channel 6: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed

My command is :

> ssh -L 443:REMOTE_IP:443 -L 5900:REMOTE_IP:5900 -L 5901:REMOTE_IP:5901 -l root -N REMOTE_IP
>   password: iDrac password (example by default : calvin :P)

Answer (score 0):

iDRAC's embedded SSH server may not have the capability to forward arbitrary ports, even just to itself.

You may have seen an example using a command like this:

```
ssh -L 443:dracip:443 -L 5900:dracip:5900 -L 5901:dracip:5901 -l user -N ssh_host
```

Note: this is using a separate "ssh_host" with a full-featured SSH implementation as an intermediary between the client workstation and the DRAC. The idea is that all the traffic for the forwarded ports will be transferred inside the SSH tunnel to the ssh_host, and from there onward as plain TCP connections to the DRAC IP address.

Ideally the ssh_host is in the same network segment as the DRAC, and/or the network between ssh_host and the DRAC is considered secure.